# How to Change Server.Urls with Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener

Tags: asp.net-core

Many [articles](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6) are setting up servers with Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener and are listing `--server.urls` as the variable to set the url to listen on. However, all of the articles are determining localhost as the url with a port.

**How can the url be change from localhost to a custom url?**

I've tried the following but the command exits with code 1 (0x1).

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3-beta1",
        "jQuery": "2.1.3.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": { },
        "aspnetcore50": { }
    },
    "commands": {
        "Web ": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://toolset.local:5000"
    },
    "bundleExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Is the code running as admin (that's required for custom url binding)?

Comment: Here is the output I get: http://roydukkey.com/stackoverflow-29893780/. Also, note there are no errors when the url is `http://localhost:5000`. My account is has admin priv.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a writeup on configuring self-host servers:
https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Selfhosting&referringTitle=Documentation

It was written for Katana/HttpListener, but it should all still apply for WebListener

Answer (score 1):

As @victor-hurdugaci said, make sure you are running VS as Administrator.
I had same problem right now and his answer resolved it.

My command in `project.json` is   `"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://192.168.2.2:5001",`

Also, try running `dnx . web` from console and see the output

Answer (score 0):

I have just started with Asp.NET 5 and tried to run the MS example project **self hosted**. First from my development machine then from our Intranet server.
Note: I work with VS2015 **Update 1 RC** (in Update1 there may be relevant changes)
VS deployment Settings: web - CLR-Type: .NET core
My project was stored on a network-share.
First I have tried to deploy the project (stored on network share) to a directory on the local file system and received error-messages like:

```
EPERM, open 'C:\Windows\npm-debug.log'
```

I then have copied my project from the network share to a local drive (it seems, as load / deploy projects from network share don't work out-of-the-box).
**Update: If you map a drive, it works** (only UNC-Path seems not to work)
**After copy the project to a local drive**, I was able to deploy to a directory on a local drive.
Then, I had to edit the file **[app-directory]\approot\src\[app-name]\hosting.ini**:
change localhost:5000 to [IP-to-my-machine]:5000
Then I had to define a inbound-roule for the port 5000 in the windows-firewall to my machine.
Then I had to start the file [app-directory]\web.cmd **as administrator**
After doing that, I was able to start the self-hosting web application from my machine (over my IP:5000) and also from another machine in the LAN.

After that, I have done the same on our intranet-server (copy the directory to the intranet server and do the same as on my local machine, but use the server IP address) and it also works from the intranet server (also over the DNS-Name).