# ASP.NET5 CLR website on Azure Windows Server 2016 running but giving 404 NOT FOUND in browser

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, windows-server-2016

I am trying to run a sample ASP.NET5 MVC application on a Windows Server 2016 instance hosted on Azure. All indicators show that the application runs fine on the server, but when i try to browse the URL (using the server's hostname or public IP) i get a 404. NOT FOUND error.

- The ports are open in Azure and in the firewall.
- The application runs on Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.Weblistener
- The runtime is clr-1.0.0-beta5 x64. I have verified that the runtime is properly installed and is being used.
- I have published the app from VS2015 and transferred to the server manually, i run it with the command "web.cmd" which is autogenerated, and i get a neat output saying:

`info    : [Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener] Start
info    : [Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener] Listening on prefix: http://localhost:80/
Started`

When i run the application in exacly the same way on my local developer machine i get exacly the same output, and it works to browse localhost:80 to get to the website.

This, to me, indicates that

1. The app runs properly
2. The ports are configured correctly (when i turn off the webserver i get a different error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT instead of the 404)

My guess is that there's something wrong with the WebListener server, not properly routing incoming requests to my application, or perhaps something is wrong with my MVC code (although it works fine on localhost).

Sorry for a rather vague question, i am open to all ideas and input, and please feel free to ask further questions so i can provide more information.

Cheers,
Niko

Comment: You won't be able to use `localhost` when accessing a remote site.  I don't know what the solution is, but that's likely the problem.

Comment: @Amy I must have phrased it poorly - of course i am not trying to connect to my Azure server by the localhost address, i have an IP and a hostname for it. I'll try to edit the OP a bit to clarify.

Comment: Well, if you're getting a 404 it isn't a firewall issue.  How are your MVC routes set up?

Comment: The output from `web.cmd` above indicates that it's listening on `http://localhost:80/`. Bindings in Windows (at least in IIS) are very specific so `localhost:80` is not necessarily the same as `127.0.0.1:80` or `IpAddressOfMachine:80`. Your comment to @Amy suggests you're trying to connect via another IP/Hostname - does `web.cmd` set up bindings for these?

Comment: @Rob Thank you very much, this was exacly my problem. I changed the hosting.ini file which is autogenerated to --server-urls to my hostname instead of localhost, and it works fine now. Thanks for your both help. Can i mark comments as answers?

Comment: ah ha!  another mystery solved.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rob and @Amy pointed out, the problem was that the WebListener only had a binding for the http://localhost:80 address. When i tried to browse it using my server hostname, i got the 404 Not Found.

The solution was to change the --server.urls in hosting.ini from http://localhost:80 to my proper hostname. Also found more information on the answer here:

[How to Change Server.Urls with Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893780/how-to-change-server-urls-with-microsoft-aspnet-server-weblistener) (stackoverflow.com)